# How do i calculate total amount for specific id in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**I have two tables invoices and invoice_items. What I want is to sum amount for each invoice id and show in my view.**

**Invoice Table**

- id

**invoice_items table**

- id
- invoice_id
- amount

**I want to sum amount column for specific invoice id. I am new to laravel so how do I do that with laravel eloquent.**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Model::products->sum('id');

Comment: have you  created relationship between them? what kind of results do u expect?

Comment: $amount_sum = DB::table('invoice_items')->where('invoice_id', '=', $id)->sum('amount');

Comment: I have one to many relationship

Comment: $amount_sum = DB::table('invoice_items')->where('invoice_id', '=', '1')->sum('amount'); This gives me result for invoice_id 1. Now I just want to pass the invoice_id in place of 1. I dont know how to that.

Comment: I have post my answer. plz check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using one-to-many.

#### Solution 1:

You can use `with` and `groupBy` look like this:

```php
$invoice = Invoice::with(['invoice_items' => function($query){
       $query->groupBy('invoice_id')->select('invoice_id', DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS amount_sum'));
}])->get();
```

#### Solution 2:

Or you can use `leftjoin` and `SUM` look like this:

```php
$invoice_query = InvoiceItem::groupBy('invoice_id')->select("invoice_id", DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS amount_sum'));

Invoice::leftjoin(DB::raw("({$invoice_query->toSql()}) AS ii"), 'ii.invoice_id', '=', 'invoices.id')
       ->mergeBindings($invoice_query->getQuery())
       ->select('invoices.*', 'amount_sum')
       ->get();
```

#### Solution 3:

Use **accessor**:
In your Invoice Model:

```php
protected $appends = ['amount_sum'];
public function getAmountSumAttribute()
{
    return $this->invoice_items()->where('invoice_id', $this->id)->sum('amount');
}
```

SO you can just get the sum of amounts:

```php
Invoice::all()->toJSON();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in your Invoice model has the relation of this.

```
public function invoice_items() [
   return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice_Items', 'invoice_id');
}
```

In your controller, your code should look like this.

Fetch all invoices with their invoice items total amount

```
$invoices = Invoice::with(['invoice_items' => function($query){
   $query->sum('amount');
}])->get();

return view('invoice', compact('invoices'));
```

Fetch specific invoice with invoice items total amount

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(['invoice_items' => function($query){
       $query->sum('amount');
}])->find($invoice_id);

return view('invoice', compact('invoices'));
```

Comment: I am getting null result

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with this one. I think this works
$result = \DB::table('Invoice')     
    ->join('invoice_items', 'Invoice.id', 
'=','invoice_items.invoice_id')->whereIn('Invoice.id', [1, 2, 3]))->sum('invoice_items.amount');    

if somewhere i am wrong try with exchanging table name.
```

Comment: It gives me sum of all column. I want to sum only amount of invoice id 1 and 2 and 3 seperately and show in view

Comment: 1, 2, 3 is static. What if i have 100's id's

Comment: you can put array in it also.